# Uninstalling Blueprint bundle using ActiveMQ PooledConnectionFactory causes javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Consumer is closed

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I am using Camel (tried 2.15.2 and 2.16.3) and the `activemq-camel` (tried 5.12.1 and 5.13.3) component to hook up the routes in my bundle to an external ActiveMQ server. The bundle is deployed in Karaf (tried 3.0.5 and 4.0.5) and started via a Blueprint context (containing the Camel context). The bundle in question only contains an amq producer.

As long as no messages were exchanged there is no issue with uninstalling/restarting the bundle. But any time after the first message exchange I receive a javax.jms.IllegalStateException when uninstalling the bundle:

```
2016-05-30 17:12:51,937 | WARN  | V.XACML.REQUEST] | TemporaryQueueReplyManager       | 75 - org.apache.camel.camel-jms -
2.16.3 | ID-Ralfs-MacBook-Pro-local-59456-1464621134397-7-2 | Exception inside the DMLC for Temporary ReplyTo Queue for destination DEV.XACML.REQUEST, refreshing ReplyTo destination javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Consumer is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.checkClosed(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:880)[64:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:641)[64:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.13.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledMessageConsumer.receive(PooledMessageConsumer.java:67)[64:org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi:5.13.3]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:430)[106:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:310)[106:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)[106:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)[106:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)[106:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992)[106:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_77]
```

This then causes an infinite re-try to connect back to the temporary queue:

```
2016-05-30 17:12:51,940 | WARN  | V.XACML.REQUEST] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | 106 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms - 3.2.14.RELEASE_1 | ID-Ralfs-MacBook-Pro-local-59456-1464621134397-7-2 | Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'temporary' - trying to recover. Cause: The Consumer is closed
2016-05-30 17:12:51,941 | INFO  | V.XACML.REQUEST] | PooledConnection                 | 64 - org.apache.activemq.activemq-osgi - 5.13.3 | ID-Ralfs-MacBook-Pro-local-59456-1464621134397-7-2 | failed to delete Temporary Queue "temp-queue://ID:Ralfs-MacBook-Pro.local-59467-1464621151437-1:2:1" on closing pooled connection: The connection is already closed
2016-05-30 17:12:51,943 | ERROR | V.XACML.REQUEST] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | 106 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms - 3.2.14.RELEASE_1 | ID-Ralfs-MacBook-Pro-local-59456-1464621134397-7-2 | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'temporary' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: null
[rest of component shutdown logs...]
2016-05-30 17:12:56,944 | ERROR | V.XACML.REQUEST] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | 106 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms - 3.2.14.RELEASE_1 |  | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'temporary' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: null
2016-05-30 17:13:01,948 | ERROR | V.XACML.REQUEST] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | 106 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms - 3.2.14.RELEASE_1 |  | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'temporary' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: null
2016-05-30 17:13:06,953 | ERROR | V.XACML.REQUEST] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | 106 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms - 3.2.14.RELEASE_1 |  | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'temporary' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: null
2016-05-30 17:13:11,956 | ERROR | V.XACML.REQUEST] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | 106 - org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms - 3.2.14.RELEASE_1 |  | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'temporary' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: null
[...]
```

How would I have to set up my context in order to support bundle re-starts and still use temporary queues for request-reply messaging?

My current configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq.broker.url} />
    <property name="userName" value="${activemq.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}" />
    <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactoryProducer" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="${activemq.maxconnections}" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfigProducer" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactoryProducer" />
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="false" />
    <property name="replyToDeliveryPersistent" value="false" />
    <property name="transacted" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="amq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfigProducer" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Doubt that will work. Restarting the bundle means the connection to the temp queue is gone and in the best case a new temp queue should be created, rather than try to connect a non-existing one.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti, why should this not work? I would think this just a question of properly cleaning up after oneself on bundle stop/restart.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but if you do a bundle restart, don't you lose the connection to the temp queue? By the way strange that this happens with activemq, doing bundle stop or restrat with rabbitmq using temp req/reply queues works fine.

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti, yes, of course you loose the connection. And AMQ deletes the temp queue in response. So the client should not attempt to reconnect to that queue but "simply" abandon it, I guess.

Comment: Maybe you have already looked here? http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Activemq-consumer-is-closing-td5731140.html

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti, yes, I had found this thread before and also checked out the issue [AMQ-4366](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4366) that boday referred to. But as far as I understand the issue it is the opposite of mine. With connections to temp queues being closed prematurely. In my case they are not cleared when they should.